# Can not connect with mosquitto MQTT brocker inside docker

Tags: python, docker, mqtt, paho

I have a mosquitto mqtt brocker running in docker. I am starting it is a docker compose file. Now I am trying to connect with the broker, it was working locally. When I try to connect as a docker container it is not working although I have changed the host/brocker address from local to compose image name. How can I make it work ?

Here What I have tried
Docker compose ( edited )

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
       - pgdatapg:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    networks:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/mosquitto/conf
      - ./data:/mosquitto/data
      - ./log:/mosquitto/log

  app:
    restart: always
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - postgres

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    pgdatapg:
```

and part of my python

```
broker = "mosquitto"
port = 1883
topic = "py/mqtt/test"
def connect_mqtt():
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    return client
```

Here is the conf file

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log

listener 1883
## Authentication ##
allow_anonymous false
password_file /mosquitto/conf/mosquitto.conf
```

I am getting the following error

```
| ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: You need to expose the port to the outside world: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports

Comment: I just id with 1883 . it is still showing the error .

Comment: Where is the python code running?

Comment: in docker .it worked when it was local host

Comment: Edit the question to include the full service file, not just the mosquitto section

Answer (score 0):

When running with docker compose, the containers started as services by default are placed on dedicated docker overlay network named after the project (which defaults to the dir name the `docker-compose.yml` file is held in) e.g. network called `foo_default`

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Services are only accessible from other containers that are connected to the same network (and to the host via what ever ports are exposed).

So if you only have mosquitto in the `docker-compose.yml` then no other containers will be able to connect to it. If you include the container that the python is running in as a service in the compose file then it will be able to connect.

You can also change the networks containers connect to in the compose file.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks

EDIT:

You have forced the mosquitto service to use `network_mode: host` network so it's not on the same `postgres` network as the `app`. Containers can be on multiple networks, but mosquitto should not be bound to the host network to make all this work.

EDIT2:

You are also not setting a username/password in app even though you have require authentication in `mosquitto.conf` and you are pointing the password file at the config file which just won't work. I suggest you remove the last line of the `mosquitto.conf` file and set `allow_anonymous true`.

P.s. I suspect that the mosquitto container currently isn't actually starting due to the last line of the config file.

Comment: I have added my complete docker compose. could you please take a look ?

Comment: I have added `    networks:
      - postgres` and still same error

Comment: To where? What you've posted `mosquitto` is not on th same network as the app

Comment: I have added to the mosquitto now but same error. I am updating the compose file

Comment: I have changed it. still same error. Now I am sharing the same network

Comment: Your `mosquitto.conf` is also wrong

Comment: Thank you for the info, however could you please correct it ? that would be REALLY helpful.

Comment: I can't because I don't know what's in the `conf` dir. But `password_file` should point to your password file